# How to fix website layout when i zoom it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

When i zoom my website on 200px, it goes to mobile device mode.

i want to fix it in desktop layout, don't want to scale it with zoom.

I opened google.com and zoom it to 200px. it's zoomed but size of layout didn't change.

I did this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
});
</script>
```

This is help me to open website in desktop mode even open in Mobile but when i zoom it on desktop it goes to mobile responsive mode.

So what to do so that my website don't go in mobile responsive mode when i zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

add this inside your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: @ManishTiwari im sorry i misunderstood your question

Comment: Okay dont judje me on this i never tried it but put this into your css `body{width: 100vw; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* height:width ratio = 9/16 = .5625  */
    background: pink;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh; /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */}`